# Unable to horizontally align a Container in the middle of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Desired result is to align the Container in the middle of the screen. Vertical alignment is done. But horizontal alignment is not happening.

I expected that crossAxisAlignment.center would take care of it.

Desired result:

[image: Desired]

Current outcome:

[image: Current]

```
return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text(
            'Failed to login. Try again later.',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red[800],
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 30),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Try wrapping the column in a Center widget.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your container with a Center widget.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'Failed to login. Try again later.',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red[800],
        ),
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 30),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```